# One variable two values Python

Tags: python

Hy people.
I have one variable (at least one name) but when i try to access to in in different ways it is has different value. Here is code.

```
class Sabirac(object):
    nums=[]
    def __init__(self):
            self.nums=[5,4]                
            for i in range (1,11):
                    self.add(randint(1, 100))
    @classmethod
    def add(self,num):
            self.nums.append(num)
    @classmethod
    def calc_sum(self):
            csum=0
            for num in self.nums:
                    csum=csum+num
            return csum
    @classmethod
    def ispis(self):
            return self.nums
```

Here is output.

```
b=Sabirac()
b.nums
[5, 4]
b.ispis()
[85, 72, 6, 42, 34, 20, 77, 89, 91, 47]
c=Sabirac()
c.ispis()
[85, 72, 6, 42, 34, 20, 77, 89, 91, 47, 36, 61, 81, 41, 60, 42, 67, 56, 40, 99]
c.nums
[5, 4]
```

So I made class Sabirac and the acces directly to variable nums and have output

```
[5, 4]
```

After that I access same variable through method ispis(). However it give me completely different values

```
[85, 72, 6, 42, 34, 20, 77, 89, 91, 47]
```

Then if I create new instance of class c=Sabirac() and call c.ispis() my output will be:

```
[85, 72, 6, 42, 34, 20, 77, 89, 91, 47, 36, 61, 81, 41, 60, 42, 67, 56, 40, 99]
```

note that is just append 10 values to b.ispis().

Could someone please tell me what is going on here??

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `@classmethod`? (BTW, if you really **do** want class methods, the first argument should be called `cls`, not `self`, by convention and to make things clearer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nums` is a class variable. Not an instance variable. If you want `nums` to be an object variable you have to declare into the `__init__` method of the class(or some other method).

For instance:

```
class X:
    class_var = 3

    def __init__(self):
        X.class_var = X.class_var + 1
        self.instance_var =  3



>>> a = X()
>>> print(a.class_var)
>>> 4
>>> print(a.instance_var)
>>> 3

>>> b = X()
>>> print(b.class_var)
>>> 5
>>> print(a.instance_var)
>>> 3
```

Comment: That's not a very helpful answer to someone who doesn't understand this situation.

Comment: `self.nums` *is* being assigned in OP's `__init__`.

Comment: @Wooble yes but **assigned** is not the same as **declared** that is what I said in my answer.

Comment: Considering Python doesn't have variable declaration, I don't see the distinction you're trying to make here.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sabirac(object):
    nums=[]
    def __init__(self):
            self.nums=[5,4]                
            for i in range (1,11):
                    self.add(randint(1, 100))

    def add(self,num):
            self.nums.append(num)

    def calc_sum(self):
            csum=0
            for num in self.nums:
                    csum=csum+num
            return csum

    def ispis(self):
            return self.nums
```

dont make your methods class methods ... it is clear you are lacking some of the knowledge about what these are

for example

```
class People:
     my_people = {}
     def __init__(self,name,age):
         self.name = name
         self.age = age
         People.my_people[name] = self    
     def birthday(self):
         #a birthday happens to an instance (or a person, not to people in general)
         self.age += 1
     @classmethod
     def get_person(cls,name):
         #this is asking the People class for an instance of a person
         return cls.my_people[name]

  billy = People("billy",8)
  billy.birthday()
  susan = People("susan",12)

  #somewhere else
  susan = People.get_person("susan") #call the classmethod
  susan.birthday()
```

Answer (score 0):

On first glance, it seems irrelevant that we have a `nums` at class level:

it gets shadowed at class instantiation in `__init__()`.

So each object has an instance variable with `5` and `4` in it, which you get with `b.nums` resp. `c.nums`.

But all your methods operate on the class, as you use `@classmethod`.

Thus, `self` should be replaced by `cls`, as it really represents the class.

And they modify the class attribute `nums`, which is shared by all instances.